# How to drop rows (or subset other rows) based on values in lists in pandas? Create mutually exclusive subsets of dfs

Tags: python, pandas, subset, drop

How to drop rows which have at least 1 element from both the lists? Looking for something iterative over more than 100 columns.
Minimal example with 3 columns is:

```
list1 = ["abc1", "def"]
list2 = ["ghi", "ghj"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
                     "col1": ["abc1", "ghj", "ghi", "abc1", "","def","ghj","abc1","abc1"], 
                     "col2": ["abc1", "abc1", "dfg", "dfg", "ghi","dfg","","ghj","abc1"], 
                     "col3": ["abc1", "qrst", "dfg", "dfg", "dfg","dfg","abc1","ghi","abc1"]})
```

```
  index col1    col2    col3
0   0   abc1    abc1    abc1
1   1   ghj     abc1    qrst
2   2   ghi     dfg     dfg
3   3   abc1    dfg     dfg
4   4           ghi     dfg
5   5   def     dfg     dfg
6   6   ghj             abc1
7   7   abc1    ghj     ghi
8   8   abc1    abc1    abc
```

Row numbers 1, 6, 7 must be dropped because they have elements from both the lists. Finaldf should be:

```
 index  col1    col2    col3
0   0   abc1    abc1    abc1
1   2   ghi     dfg     dfg
2   3   abc1    dfg     dfg
3   4           ghi     dfg
4   5   def     dfg     dfg
5   8   abc1    abc1    abc1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
finaldf = df[ ~(df.isin(list1).any(axis=1) & df.isin(list2).any(axis=1)) ].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
   index  col1  col2  col3
0      0  abc1  abc1  abc1
1      2   ghi   dfg   dfg
2      3  abc1   dfg   dfg
3      4         ghi   dfg
4      5   def   dfg   dfg
5      8  abc1  abc1  abc1
```